# System Environment Variable Not Found

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest, scalatest-maven-plugin

I'm using MacOS and I have defined a few environment variables inside `.bash_profile` file. I'm running the Scalatest Framework inside IntelliJ IDEA, and I have defined my test class file:

```scala
class ApiCheckerTest extends FunSuite {
    val userid: String = sys.env(Constants.KEY_CLOUD_USERNAME)   //Value of parameter is CLOUD_USERNAME
    val password: String = sys.env(Constants.KEY_CLOUD_PASSWORD)
    val url: String = sys.env(Constants.KEY_CLOUD_DB2_URL)

    test("ApiChecker.getAuthToken.noUserPasswordUrl") {
        val apiChecker = new ApiChecker()
        assert(apiChecker.getAuthToken("", "", "").isEmpty)
    }

    //... <Other test cases>
}
```

When I run this Test class file, I get an error shown below:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: key not found: CLOUD_USERNAME 
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: CLOUD_USERNAME
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
    at ApiCheckerTest.<init>(ApiCheckerTest.scala:6)     <- points to declaration of val userid
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.genSuiteConfig(Runner.scala:1428)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$31.apply(Runner.scala:1236)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$31.apply(Runner.scala:1235)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:284)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1235)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1011)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1506)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:131)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
```

Now when I open scala terminal and run `sys.env()` there, I get an output:

```
scala> sys.env("CLOUD_USERNAME")
res0: String = sparker0i
```

If this can work inside Scala terminal, why does this not work in the Test class in IntelliJ?

Comment: Are you sure IntelliJ itself runs in an environment in which this variable is set? (i.e., exit intellij, run new terminal session, make sure that the variable is set and then run intellij from that terminal)

Comment: Ok, so do I have to run IntelliJ from the terminal than opening it from the Launchpad?

Comment: I guess launchpad will be OK too, but I don't know what you should do to make Launchpad recognize your new variables. Does it work when running from terminal?

Comment: Got it. A restart to IDE helped

Answer (score 0):

I created these environment variables after I opened IntelliJ IDEA. Restarting the IDE fixed the problems